# Take elements from each group in Polars where the groups are not even

Tags: python, python-polars

How do I take the first `n` elemets of a group where `n` > `G` and  `G = number of items in group`?

For example,

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,1,1,2,3,3,3], y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
df.groupby("x").agg(pl.all().take([0, 2]))
```

The above returns a `ComputeError: take indices are out of bounds` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`head` will not error on `n > G`. (`maintain_order=True` is listed for output purposes):

```py
n = 2
df.groupby("x", maintain_order=True).agg(pl.all().head(n))
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ x   ┆ y         │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [1, 2]    │
│ 2   ┆ [4]       │
│ 3   ┆ [5, 6]    │
└─────┴───────────┘
```

Your question has `take([0, 2])`, suggesting you want every other element. In lieu of `take_every(2)` also erroring, you can do a `filter` within the aggregation and refer to the resulting index of the array with `cumcount` to do the actual filtering:

```py
df.groupby("x", maintain_order=True).agg(
  pl.col('y').filter(pl.col('y').cumcount() % 2 == 0)
)
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ x   ┆ y         │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [1, 3]    │
│ 2   ┆ [4]       │
│ 3   ┆ [5, 7]    │
└─────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: I assumed that their usage of `take([0,2])` was as if it were like `range` where they're trying to say they want the 0 and 1 element.